# C++: Is dividing by cos(x) safe?

Tags: c++

I have to debug some old code. One issue is identifying and getting rid of all floating point divisions by zero.
There aren't many of them, but the one I find most frequently is this:

```
dA = bB / cos(x);
```

and sin and tan too. `x` is typically a coordinate in degrees, so `tan`, `cos` and `sin` could easily be zero. This code has been around and running for decades, and since it is safety critical it's been tested all over the place.

**edit1:** `x` is a `double` and is generated typically after conversion from UTM. The value in degree is in the range -180.0 to +180.0.

**edit 2:** of course it's in radians, it gets converted. It could still be zero, though

So my question is, why has it never crashed? Am I missing something?

**edit 3** I followed up all the comments and found the right answer for me. This was started by a nasty exception. The reason we got an exception was that we built in somebody else's code (provided by the customer) which is very mathy. They had switched floating point exceptions on (/fp:except), which is of course fine if you need it. They did not, however, switch it off again, so our code started throwing exceptions where it never had before. This was mended by calling the new stuff via the dll instead of the exe, but left me with the action of making people happy again.
I am going through the code looking at every division to see if it can be a division by zero, and if that is a bad thing, and since I now know that trigonometric operations are mostly happy with NaN, this is not going to be too bad. I still have to check them all. Ouch.

Comment: Without known how `x` is generate we can't tell if it's safe or not.

Comment: without knowing the context, it's even harder to tell what you want to achieve!

Comment: because of floating point arithmetic, `x` cannot be exactly `pi/2` and therefore `cos(x)` might never return exactly `0.0`. Don't know though

Comment: Floating point exceptions are disabled? Floating point division by zero != integer division by zero. Later can't be disabled, former - yes.

Comment: It does not matter if it can't be zero due to the computation of cosine. Thing is, it is not your job to know how it is implemented. Zero is a valid output for a function that is named cosine, therefore, you want to catch that case, at least if you can't rule it out because it can't reach zero due to the range of the arguments. Again: By encapsulation you do NOT know anything about HOW cosine is implemented, only WHAT it does. At least this is how you should act.

Comment: @Aziuth thank you, you worded it better than I did

Comment: Just store it in a `const` variable, check if it's 0 and act accordingly.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Floating point exceptions are disabled. Maybe it's been throwing out NaNs for years and nobody noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating-point math is designed to forge ahead in the presence of errors. Dividing a non-zero value by 0 produces infinity; dividing 0 by 0 produces NaN. Both of these values can be used in subsequent calculations, and they propagate more-or-less sensibly. If the final result has infinities or NaNs that tells you that something went wrong along the way, and you have to figure out what caused it: bad data or bad code.

Whether or not this is "safe" depends on what you mean by that word. If you don't know what you're doing, nothing is safe. If you understand how errors propagate in floating-point code you can work with it and produce robust, reliable results. (Sorry if that's a bit over the top; I **really, really** hate the word "safe" when it's applied to software, because it's usually empty)

Answer (score 3):

The code runs because the zeros of `cos(x)` lie at `pi/2 + k*pi; k € Z`. But `pi` cannot be represented exactly. A complete zero is therefore unlikely.

Comment: Yes, that's why `cos(pi/2)` cannot be exactly `0`. I should have added this point in my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

`double` has [special value for infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity). Division by `0` gives this special value.

Note that `x` should be in radians, not degrees.

Just tested in some C++ compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#define USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  std::cout << (1 / std::cos(M_PI_2)) << "\n";
  std::cout << (1 / std::sin(0)) << "\n";
}
```

And got:

```
1.63312e+16
inf
```

So `1 / cos(M_PI_2)` can be very big number, not even infinity. I suppose it's OK for day-to-day numerical computation.

Comment: Yes, radians, oops. But it can still be zero, so the sin or tan would be zero. Even with the built in inaccuracy of doubles, it must have hit zero sometime in the last 30 years.

Answer (score 2):

Side note: The function cosine is zero at 90° Degrees (or π/2 Radians). This from a spacial point of view corresponds to something which is ... vertical. Assuming that your code has never to deal with something vertical there is a high possibility that it will continue running for a while without crashes. Please share more details about `x` which, should be radians, not degrees.

Comment: I don't want to make it too specific, but here goes: I am converting from one co-ordinate system to another, in this case UTM to degree. So my coordinates are east (range -180 to +180) and north (range -90 to +90). So if I have an east value of 90 degrees I will indeed have cos(x) = 0, whether I ask in radian or in degree. But I want my question to be more general.

Answer (score 1):

In broad, general, terms since the only real values with a zero cosine are irrational (i.e. odd multiples of `pi/2`) and floating point values cannot represent irrational real values, it is not possible for any floating point value to exist that has a zero cosine.

That sort of argument may be enough in non-critical code.   It is (depending on system requirements) unacceptable in high criticality (e.g. safety-critical) code.

Similarly, a claim like "it has been tested all over the place" is not necessarily acceptable either - if you want to use such an argument (referred to, more formally in some safety standards as a service history argument) then the onus is on you to justify it.

I would expect, if the system has previously been accepted as acceptable for use in safety-related applications like you say, there would be some analysis of the circumstances in which a statement like `dA = bB / cos(x)` might produce an erroneous result (e.g. floating point overflow, division by zero, ...).  That analysis would depend on how the `cos()` function is implemented - e.g. what algorithm it uses within your chosen standard library.   Analysis would then consider the implication any erroneous results would have on overall system behaviour (not just the program) of such an erroneous result, and the likelihood of occurrence, given the possible range of program inputs.    Essentially, this means a completed risk assessment - if the risk is acceptably low (in the context of the system) then it will have been accepted.

Put it this way:   imagine that this code is part of firmware that controls an elevator.  You are going to be updating this code, recompiling it, and installing the updated firmware into several elevators.  Now imagine if the value of `dA` affects the speed at which the elevator travels - so the hazard is that the elevator hits the ground at speeds sufficient to kill the occupants.    A number of family members you care for regularly use one of the elevators you are updating.    Would you accept an "it's been tested all over the place" argument?   Or would you want a more robust argument?

Comment: Well, since it was actually me who tested it, I mean, "it was tested according to safety critical guidelines and released for doing dangerous things". We did test all possible variations on null degrees, because there were indeed a few problems there, but this one never popped up. Which is why it's bothering me, because it should have.

Comment: Possibly.   It depends on a few things, including the floating point representation and the algorithm used (in code or hardware) to compute the cosine.   The thing is, to provide evidence through testing, you need to make a case that the testing you do is sufficient.    If the testing is insufficient (by whatever criteria are relevant to your system requirements) to explain the "pass" result, then that would account for your discomfort.I know that safety-critical guidelines are often treated as a checklist, but there can be a point where it is necessary to reason about your system more deeply